# I want to place 3rd division content (i.e image) just beside the second division (i.e animate)

Tags: css

I want to place 3rd division content (i.e image) just beside the second division  (i.e animate).I think there should be some CSS properties which will resolve the problem.

**Markup**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            #header {
                background-color:blue;
                height:100px;
                width:1000px;
            }

            #animate {
                background-color:red;
                height:130px;
                width:500px;
                float:left;
            }

            #Image {
                background-color:green;
                height:130px;
                width:500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">Header Section</div>
        <div id="animate">Animation section</div>
        <div id="Image"> Image section</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me & will above `css` be compatible with all browsers?

Help would appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more clarification...

Answer (score 1):

You can use float property for that as below:

```
#Image {
background-color:green;
height:130px;
width:500px;

float: right;
}
```

Hope this helps.!!

Answer (score 0):

insert your two `div` in a container and add a `float` property to `#Image`

**Snippet :**

```css
#header {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:1000px;
}

#content {
  height:130px;
  width:1000px;
}

#animate {
  background-color:red;
  height:130px;
  width:500px;
  float:left;
}

#Image {
  background-color:green;
  height:130px;
  width:500px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">Header Section</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="animate">Animation section</div>
            <div id="Image"> Image section</div>      
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @sameer if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.